# how to dynamically allocate a 2d array with the help of a function in C

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, dereference, pointer-to-pointer

```
void alloc_matrix(int ***mat, int *m, int *n) {
    mat = (int **)malloc(*m * sizeof(int *));

    for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
        mat[i] = (int *)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < *n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);

    for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
            printf('\n');
        }

}
```

i wanted to read and allocate the matrix in the same function, but when i call it, nothing will print, i think there is something wrong with the way i used the pointers, but i cant figure out what is the problem

Comment: Possible dupe?  [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: "i wanted to read and allocate the matrix in the same function" Not the best idea. Separation of concerns is the name of the game in programming. A function should do one thing and do it well.

Comment: But the first error is in the first line, and your compiler should have warned you about it. If not, you should uninstall it and download a modern compiler.

Comment: See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4dehK7Ej4). For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Comment: Finally, functions in C are able to *return values*. Take advantage of it. Does `malloc` receive a pointer argument? No, it returns a value. Your function should do the same. Prefer to return a value over an out-parameter if possible.

Comment: Heed what @n.m. said - `int **alloc_matrix(int m, int n) { ... }` is a **lot** easier to understand.  N.B. - also remove the `int *n` and just use `int n` - you're not changing `m` or `n` in the caller so there's absolutely no need for the indirection of a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions like `&mat[i][j]` or `mat[i][j]` used in the for loops and the expression `mat` used in the statement that allocates memory for an array of pointers

```
mat = (int **)malloc(*m * sizeof(int *));

for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
    mat[i] = (int *)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < *n; j++)
        scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);

for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        printf('\n');
    }
```

are incorect.

Instead you have to write

```
*mat = (int **)malloc(*m * sizeof(int *));

for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
    ( * mat )[i] = (int *)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < *n; j++)
        scanf("%d", &( *mat )[i][j]);

for(int i = 0; i < *m; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", ( *mat )[i][j]);
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

That is the parameter `mat` has the type `int ***`. This means that the original pointer of the type `int **` is passed to the function by reference indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus you need to dereference the parameter to get an access to the original pointer.

And this call of `printf`

```
printf('\n');
```

where you are incorrectly using the integer character constant `'\n'` instead of the string literal `"\n"` should be placed after the inner for loop.

Also there is no sense to declare `m` and `n` as pointers. The function could be declared at least like

```
void alloc_matrix(int ***mat, int m, int n) {
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alloc_matrix( int ***mat, int m, int n ) 
{
    *mat = ( int ** )malloc( m * sizeof( int * ) );

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ( * mat )[i] = ( int * )malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf( "%d", &( *mat )[i][j] );

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf( "%d ", ( *mat )[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { M = 2, N = 3 };
    int **mat = NULL;

    alloc_matrix( &mat, M, N );

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        free( mat[i] );
    }
    free( mat );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

The first two lines is the user input and the next two lines is the output of elements of the dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: It still wont let me read the elements of the matrix

Comment: when i run this it gives an error on line free(mat[i]), it says the value is neither an array nor a pointer; also, is it mandatory to initialize the matrix with NULL in main? cant i do it in the function?

Comment: @MXF Please at least copy and paste the demonstration program as is. Can you?

Comment: I'd also through in the cast of `malloc()` being unnecessary. And even add that if you are casting to get around a compiler warning -- that should tell you you have other problems to fix. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: what my challenge is it says each time i input the character L in main, i read m and n (rows and columns for a matrix) then i allocate dynamically that matrix; i do this over and over, i can read as many characters as i want. my problem is how do i reallocate the memory for each new matrix, do i use realloc() after scanf inside the fucntion or?

Comment: @MXF You can free the  already allocated matrix as shown in the demonstration program and allocate a new matrix using the function.